# How to make foreach work with this PHP script - GET API

Tags: php, api

I'm working on a script that will retrieve API information of the 'near earth objects' from NASA's website. User selects date, api grabs the information and displays it. How do I fix the foreach in this script? would appreciate some help with this.

```
$jsonAsteroids = file_get_contents("https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2018-08-01&end_date=2018-08-04&api_key=NNKOjkoul8n1CH18TWA9gwngW1s1SmjESPjNoUFo");
$data = json_decode($jsonAsteroids, true);
echo "<h4>Retrieving the first element (i.e. \"links\") of the JSON structure</h4>";
var_dump( $data["links"]);
echo "<h4>Retrieving the first element (i.e. \"next\") inside the \"links\" element</h4>";
echo( $data["links"]["next"]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close. Your main issue was that you used `json_decode(..., true);` which gives you an array, but then used the object->property syntax instead of object['property']. My suggestion is to use `json_decode` without the 2nd argument in this case.

Finally, your 2nd `foreach` was malformed.

```
<?php

$result = file_get_contents("https://api.nasa.gov/neo/rest/v1/feed?start_date=2018-08-01&end_date=2018-08-04&api_key=NNKOjkoul8n1CH18TWA9gwngW1s1SmjESPjNoUFo");
$data = json_decode($result);


foreach ($data->near_earth_objects as $date => $objects) {

    echo "<p>" . count($objects) . " objects detected on $date</p>";
    echo "<ol>";

    foreach ($objects as $object) {
        echo "<li>" . $object->name . " <a href='" . $object->nasa_jpl_url . "'>" . $object->nasa_jpl_url . "</a><br>";
        echo "Diameter of the object: " . $object->estimated_diameter->meters->estimated_diameter_min . "-" . $object->estimated_diameter->meters->estimated_diameter_max . " metres<br>";
        echo "<ul>";
        foreach ($object->close_approach_data as $close_approach) {
            echo "<li>Close approach: " . $close_approach->close_approach_date . " traveling at a velocity of " . $close_approach->relative_velocity->kilometers_per_hour . " km/h " . "missing " . $close_approach->orbiting_body . " by " . $close_approach->miss_distance->kilometers . " km</li> ";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
    }

    echo "</ol>";
}
```

[image: Output]